# Removing right horizontal gap from hidden jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a button that show/hides a jPanel and then calls pack(); but after hiding the jPanel horizontal gap that was between panel and gap that was to the right of that panel add up and create a huge horizontal gap to the right.

I am using default layout which is border layout.

Here is what happens now:
[image]

And how I would want it to look like after hiding a jPanel
[image]

```
private void normalDistributionTableToggleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                              
    normalDistributionTablePanel.setVisible(!normalDistributionTablePanel.isVisible());
    pack();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    System.out.println("Toggle normal distribution table.");
}
```

Comment: 1. `revalidate();` and  `repaint()`; are contraproductive in context that `pack()` is called, 2. all those three code lines can be useless if is there used `NullLayout`. 3. override `getPreferredSize` for all `JPanel`(s), 4 use propotional `LayoutManager` that accepts `getPreferredSize`, 5. for better help sooner post an `SSCCE` / `MCVE`, short, runnable, compilable with empty `JPanel`s by using hardcoded `Dimension` from `getPreferredSize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using default layout which is border layout.

You are nesting panels which use different layout managers. If you look at your second image with both components shown you will see the gap is larger on the right than the left.

Some layout managers, like the FlowLayout will handle the visibility of the components correctly so the gap on the right will remain constant.

On the other hand if you use a layout manager like a BoxLayout and add a "horizontal strut" between components, then when you hide the panel you will know have two struts together which will give the increased gap.

If you use an IDE to generate your code, then I have no IDE what the GroupLayout code is doing, but I would suggest you don't use the IDE and write the layout code manually so you can control it better.

Without seeing your simple demo code (SSCCE / MCVE) we can't give a concrete solution.

Comment: Yes I am using the GUI builder, I am nesting jpanels directly in jframe should I next all jpanels in one jpanel that is then nexted in jframe?

I believe the 'horizontal strut' is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: @Higeath, So don't use the horizontal strut on the right of your panel. Instead you can use and `EmptyBorder` to give more space to the panel. Then when the panel is hidden the EmptyBorder is also hidden. The point is if you use Swing and design the layout you can have more control then letting the IDE do the layout and generate the code.